# Cloth simulation on human distance

Tags: cloth-simulation, makehuman

I am trying to simulate a tshirt on a person. Problem that I have encountered is a distance between tshirt and a body of the person. Both objects are meshed, tshirt has a cloth option chosen (distance 0.001m) and human has a collisions chosen. How can I reduce that distance? On a picture below it is clearly visible, black and orange one at the shoulders. Another issue is with the hand movement simulation, I am not sure what I am missing because when I put hands in a different position the tshirt is not reacting to it even though collissions between those two things are there.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Edit 1: I attach screenshot as requested. Please see menu on the right hand side.

[image]

Edit 2: *Did you mean Thickness Outer property?*

I think it helped but I still do have a problem when avatar changes the hands position. I guess maybe I am trying to do the animation wrong? Because when in Pose Mode cloth do not collide with the arms as on a picture below. I was looking for some tutorial on yt but unfortunately did not find anything helpful.

[image]

Edit 3: I attach my file. I guess that issue could be related to the wrong animation and changing position of hands to dynamically, or I am missing some setting.

Thank you all for help.

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the distance on the body to .001 to close the gap. It looks like you have assigned weights with the arms hanging down and not in a t-pose. Use a t-pose when setting up parenting. It may be that your weights are not assigned correctly as the rig is not  recognizing the arms as arms, but rather part of the torso. Check the weights and adjust or simply start fresh in a t-pose

Comment: I am not sure where to find "distance on the body" variable? The one on the cloth is already set to 0.001.

As I was checking weights they look okay, the model was free downloaded from the net but I believe rig is configured properly.

Comment: You made the body a collision object already. Now go to the collision object properties and make that also .01. That's the distance from the body the cloth will be able to come closer. As far as the weights, if the sleeves do not move it can't be set properly. You should show a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cloth Distance

- possible issue of big distance can be object *Scale* - try **Apply scale** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for both objects.
- adjust distance for "body" object
  *Physics Properties > Collision > Soft Body & Cloth >* **Thickness Outer**

[image]

### Collision ignorance

- you have to extend **cache End** frame of Cloth sim
- also motion of hands is too drastical (from frame to frame) cloth has no time to react
- if issue persists even for slower motion try to increase **Quality Step** and **Collision Quality**

Comment: thanks for help and explanation, added a file as you suggested in my Q.